# Batch processing finding a string and commenting with '#'

Tags: batch-processing

I am writing a batch process in which I need to find a line and add '#' to the front of that line.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims == " %%x in (xyz.properties) do (
if "%%x"=="Tools" set %%x
if "%%x"=="user_name" set %%x
)
```

where ever user_name and tools occur in the file.The line should be commented with #
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Language? Interpreter? OS?

Comment: ms dos , windows , batch script :)

Comment: or for a particular line we can copy paste all to another file